# How can I create my own zip() function in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

as a personal exercise I am trying to create my own little zip() function that takes two lists and puts the items into a list of tuples. In other words if these are  my list:

```
fr = [6,5,4]
tr = [7,8,9]
```

I would expect this:

```
[(6,7), (5,8), (4,9)]
```

Here is my code:

```
def zippy(x, y):
    zipper = []
    for i in x :
        for g in y:
            t = (i,g)
        zipper.append(t)
```

What I get is: `[(6, 9), (5, 9), (4, 9)]`,
but when I define the lists inside of the function, it works as intended. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You assign to `t` three times before you append it, meaning that the first entry in your list of tuples will be the very last value in `y`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it works if the lists are contained in the function? That is making me scratch my head.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce what you experienced, could you post the code you used? I've defined the lists inside of the function rather than out and it still returns the wrong results.

Comment: Strange, you're right. Hmm, I can't step back far enough with Eclipse to find out what I was doing! Thanks again. I get a little better everyday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indexes to access same-indexes items:

```
def zippy(x, y):
    zipper = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        zipper.append((x[i], y[i]))
    return zipper
```

using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def zippy(x, y):
    return [(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

---

```
>>> fr = [6,5,4]
>>> tr = [7,8,9]
>>> zippy(fr, tr)
[(6, 7), (5, 8), (4, 9)]
```

Comment: This is great, but do you know why m original code works if the lists are defined in the function?

Comment: @SeaWolf, The reason it does not work: `zipper.append(t)` is called after the inner loop. `t[1]` will always refers the last item of `y`. I don't think it works even though the lists are defined in the function. Could you provide the code that works (which defines lists in the function)?

Comment: I can't, I ran out of "undues" in Eclipse to find out what little tweaked was producing that. Thanks, for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider that if you have two lists of different length your zip should stop when the shortest sequence ends. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
def zippy(x, y):
    iter1 = iter(x)
    iter2 = iter(y)
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(iter1), next(iter2)
        except StopIteration:
            return
```

or

```
def zippy(x, y):
    iter1 = iter(x)
    iter2 = iter(y)
    for _ in range(min(len(x), len(y))):
        yield next(iter1), next(iter2)
```

Also notice that standard zip function returns  (generator) and not a list of data! That means if you need to get data from your result you have to convert your zip result to list:

```
result = zippy(fr, tr)
print(list(result))
```

or call iterator on it

```
next(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `range()` to cycle through each index of the array.  Then, put them in a tuple and append them to the array.

```
def zippy(x, y):
    zipper = []
    for i in range(len(x)) :
        zipper.append((x[i],y[i]))
    return zipper
```

For more info on `range()`, go [here](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate both arrays at the same time to get the same indexes from both arrays

```
 def zippy(x, y):
        zipper = []
        for i,g in zip(x,y):
            t = (i,g)
            zipper.append(t)
        print(zipper)
```

Output

```
[(6, 7), (5, 8), (4, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# A zip() is a kind of map()!
def zippy(a, b):
  return map(lambda (i, a): (a, b[i]), enumerate(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the prior answers support a variable number of iterables as are supported by Python's native `zip` function. Consider the following generalized implementation which does support it. It also does not rely on `map`.

```py
def zipper(*iterables):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297966
    if not iterables:
        return (_ for _ in ())  # Without this the function runs forever.

    iterables = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    try:
        while True:
            yield tuple([next(it) for it in iterables])
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

Usage example:

```
> zipper(range(11, 15), range(20, 30))
<generator object zipper at 0x7fb6671a6420>

> list(_)
[(11, 20), (12, 21), (13, 22), (14, 23)]
```

The example in the question also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to make sure the lists are equal length before operation, you can utilize Python's `assert` statement in the function along with a list comprehension.

```py
def zippy(x,y):
    assert len(x) == len(y), 'Lists must be equal length to each other'

    return [(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

The `assert` statement makes sure that the arguments x and y are equal length. If they aren't equal, then the function won't run and will return an `AssertionError`.

Then, the functions returns a list created from a list comprehension. The list comprehension creates a tuple for each index of the lists, in which the indices are paired when the `zip()` function is called on the lists.

If you aren't worried about iterating the lists with generators like other solutions propose, then this solution will serve well.