# How can I create my own map() function in Python

Tags: python, list, map-function

I am trying to create the built-in map() function in python.
Here is my attempt:

```
def mapper(func, *sequences):
   if len(sequences) > 1:
       while True:
          list.append(func(sequences[0][0],sequences[0][0],))
       return list
   return list
```

But I am really stuck, because if the user gives e.g. 100 arguments how do i deal with those?

Comment: N.B.: do no use variable names like `list`, since these override the reference to the `list` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **use the asterisk `*`** when you call the function:

```
def mapper(func, *sequences):
       result = []
       if len(sequences) > 0:
           minl = min(len(subseq) for subseq in sequences)
           for i in range(minl):
              result.append(func(*[subseq[i] for subseq in sequences]))
       return result
```

This produces:

```
>>> import operator
>>> mapper(operator.add, [1,2,4], [3,6,9])
[4, 8, 13]
```

By using the asterisk, we unpack the iterable as separate parameters in the function call.

Note that this is still not fully equivalent, since:

1. the `sequences` should be *iterables*, not per se lists, so we can not always index; and
2. the result of a `map` in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) is an *iterable* as well, so not a list.

A more [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)-like `map` function would be:

```
def mapper(func, *sequences):
    if not sequences:
        raise TypeError('Mapper should have at least two parameters')
    iters = [iter(seq) for seq in sequences]
    try:
        while True:
            yield func(*[next(it) for it in iters])
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Note however that most Python interpreters will implement `map` closer to the interpreter than Python code, so it is definitely more efficient to use the builtin `map`, than writing your own.

> **N.B.**: it is better not to use variable names like `list`, `set`, `dict`, etc. since these will override (here locally) the reference to the `list` type. As a result a call like `list(some_iterable)` will no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

The prior [answer by Pardhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205227) attempts to decompose the problem into `mapper` and `zipper`. This is good, but it doesn't have a reasonable or working implementation of `zipper`, also to more closely match Python's native `zip`. This answer uses a more reasonable implementation of `zipper` which uses iterables more correctly.

```py
def zipper(*iterables):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297966
    if not iterables:
        return (_ for _ in ())  # Without this the function runs forever.

    iterables = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    try:
        while True:
            yield tuple([next(it) for it in iterables])
    except StopIteration:
        return


def mapper(func, *iterables):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298108
    return (func(*i) for i in zipper(*iterables))  # Note: `zipper` aims to match `zip`.
```

Usage example:

```
> mapper(lambda *i: sum(i), range(11, 15), range(20, 30))
<generator object mapper.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7ffa1a448900>

> list(_)
[31, 33, 35, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating the part of combining of the sequence or sequences logic is much more easier to read and understand.

```
def mapper(func, *args):
    for i in zip(*args):
        yield func(*i)
```

Here we are using Python inbuilt `zip`
if you want to replace it entirely with your own implementation replace with `zip` with the below `zipper` function

```
def zipper(*args):
    for i in range(len(args[0])):
        index_elements = []
        for arg in args:
            index_elements.append(arg[i])
        yield positional_elements
```

Comment: The `mapper` implementation is correct, but the `zipper` implementation is wrong and broken. `positional_elements` is not defined. Also, remember each supplied arg can optionally itself be an iterable, so `len(args[0])` doesn't make sense. Implementing `zipper` more correctly is tricky, but I have given it a shot in a separate answer.